# Create Database from SD card using SQLiteCipher

Tags: android, database, file, android-external-storage, sqlite-cipher

can anyone knows how to create database from SD Card using SQLiteCipher? link or tutorial to encrypt my database. there are some many tutorials but does not work.
then also i have this **permission in manifest**.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

which is stored database from file explorer like

```
/storage/sdcard1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wcdb to do that,it base on SQLiteCipher and you can create a encrypted db by pass specified database file path.Here is github [repo](https://github.com/Tencent/wcdb).wcdb is developed by WeChat which is biggest IM APP in China.

Comment: i install this library from dependencies?
compile 'com.tencent.wcdb:wcdb-android:1.0.5'
compile project(':wcdb')
and hard code database path like /storage/sdcard1?

Comment: that's a good news. i try it later. btw thanks for give some links :)